# Simple Displacement of Parametric Equations Dispute

Tags: calculus, parametric

A parametric equation with $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = something, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = something, has a resultant velocity vector by pythagorean theorem to be $\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2}$. Calculus theorem dictates that integral of velocity over interval equals displacement over interval. Thus it must be true that d=$\int\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2}$.

However, my dispute (wrong for some reason) is that if we treat velocity separate, displacement in x is $\int\frac{dx}{dt}$ and displacement in y is $\int\frac{dy}{dt}$ . If you know displacement along x, and displacement along y, wouldn't your total displacement from origin be $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 }$ as it is the diagonal length of the parallelogram formed by lengths x and y?

Now I've read before something like diagonal length can't be approximated treating x and y separate or something. It would be like breaking down a diagonal into infinitely tiny x and y steps, instead of just drawing a diagonal line. I don't really know, but can someone explain this better? thank you a lot

EDIT: This is even more confusing for me now as I remember how we are taught early on in maths that d=$\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 }$

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! If you want to make your question more attractive so that it gets answered as soon as possible, you might want to use $\LaTeX$... There's a fantastic tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Fixed. Apologies. edit: Also, thanks a lot. I was looking for how to make it that good!

Comment: That looks much better!

Comment: You wrote, "displacement in x is $\int(\frac{dx}{dt})^2$ and displacement in y is $\int(\frac{dy}{dt})^2$". However, I believe you meant "displacement in x is $\int\frac{dx}{dt}$ and displacement in y is $\int\frac{dy}{dt}$", i.e., the integration of the change of $x$ and $y$ over time. This results in distance values. Otherwise, with integrals of the squares, the resulting values don't make much sense, plus the units would be distance squared over time which, as far as I know, doesn't have any simple physical interpretation.

Comment: Yea, that was a mistake. Added the square for purpose of pythagorean theorem to find diagonal, the displacement value doesn't have it. Thank you.

Comment: @ebehr I appreciate you confirming it was a mistake in your comment. However, note not everyone will not read the comments and, thus, realize what you actually meant. In the future, please edit your question & fix it yourself (there is an Edit button you just need to click). In this case, I've done it for you. Also, to have me be notified when you write a comment, please type @ followed by the first few letters of my name, with you usually being able to just press Tab to finish the autocomplete suggestion.

Comment: @ebehr Instead of "Edit button", I should have said "edit link", with this being just below your question text along with "share" to the left and "delete" to the right (I believe, based on your current status).

Answer (score 2):

I understand this actually now. The "paradox" I was referring to with infinite x steps and y steps is called the staircase paradox and can be used to falsely claim pi is 4. By doing what I did with the diagonal of the x coordinate and y coordinate you are finding the distance (length) of a path that follows straight from the origin to the diagonal.

The actual arc length of a path doesn't just take into account final x and y coordinate and their formed diagonal's distance from origin. Multiple paths (e.g. a squiggly line going back and forth vs a straight line) can both reach the same coordinates. The arc length formula takes into account the true limit of a curve and thus finds its distance using integrals of velocity functions, rather than just "approximating" the shape of the distance with staircases.

EDIT: There are more proper mathematical solutions to my problem, but my answer gives a simple reasoning for anyone else that may be confused in the future.